# How to handle the null value in asp.net using Datetime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, datetime-format

this is my code to save the student record,

```
int x = clsFunctions.InsertStudent(txtStudent.Text,Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractDate.Text))
```

and the function definition is,

```
public static int InsertStudent(string Name, DateTime ContractDate)
{
int isaved = 0;
SqlParameter[] sqlprm = new SqlParameter[2];

sqlprm[0] = new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
sqlprm[0].Value = Name;

sqlprm[1] = new SqlParameter("@ContractDate", SqlDbType.Date);
sqlprm[1].Value = ContractDate;

isaved = db.ExecuteNonQueryProcedure("ProcedureName", sqlprm);
return isaved;
}
```

db.ExecuteNonQueryProcedure is the function to call ExecuteNonQuery()...

My question is that when I enter the value in ContractDate field, it works fine, the data is saved in database.. But when I left it empty, I got an error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". The ContractDate field in a table in database is 'Allow null'. How to handle this null value through this code as ContractDate field is not mandatory on the form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.DateTime` is a struct, which is non-nullable. I suggest you use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtContractDate.Text)` before attempting to use `Convert.ToDateTime` so you can know if a blank string is passed in or not and change the parameter `DateTime ContractDate` to `DateTime? ContractDate` which allows you to pass in null. See [MSDN Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
DateTime? contractDate = null; 
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtContractDate.Text))
    contractDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtContractDate.Text);
int x = InsertStudent(txtStudent.Text, contractDate);
```

Edit: I made a small mistake with ??, the operator expects the same types on both sides. You'll need to use more verbose code. I've ran a test successfully on SQL Server Express 2014 LocalDB using code similar as below.

Finally, you need to handle the null case of contractDate when you create your SqlParameter using [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as such:

```
if (ContractDate != null)
    sqlprm[1].Value = ContractDate.Value;
else
    sqlprm[1].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Comment: as per your suggestion, i modified my code, but this line is giving error, 
sqlprm[1].Value = ContractDate ?? DBNull.Value;

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if DBNull was necessary. What is the error message? What happens if you do not use DBNull.Value, and just try `sqlprm[1].Value = ContractDate;` when ContractDate is null?

Comment: i am getting this error.... (Procedure or function 'sp_tbl_Students_i' expects parameter '@ContractDate', which was not supplied.)
this is the case when ContractDate is not empty.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer. I've successfully ran a test with code similar to yours with a simple DB and stored procedure that uses the DateTime column type.

Comment: thanks bro.. at the same time, I also managed to get the right thing..  now this is working fine with me with this code,             sqlprm[1].Value = (object)ContractDate ?? DBNull.Value;   i appreciate your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" TextMode="Date" Text='<%# Eval("ColumnName").ToString() == "" ? Eval("ColumnName") : Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("ColumnName").ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") %>' runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```